# Scikit: How do i display actual labels instead of 0 and 1's as indexes for confusion matrix

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix but it has 0,1,2 as indexes/labels instead of actual labels. Is there any way to display the actual labels as index for confusion matrix in scikit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inbuilt [confusion-matrix function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), then there is a parameter `labels` in it, in which you can pass the actual labels.

From the documentation:

> labels : array, shape = [n_classes], optional List of labels to index
>   the matrix. This may be used to reorder or select a subset of labels.
>   If none is given, those that appear at least once in y_true or y_pred
>   are used in sorted order.

And if you are talking about or want to plot the confusion matrix, then you can follow this official scikit example:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py